# module selection in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a group of modules, say module_1, module_2, ... module_N. They perform similar yet different logic operations (out = logic_n). However, since the N is very large (thousands), it is unfeasible to use them in a higher level module by manually instantiate them. I was trying to write a python code for this. I was also wondering is that possible to use parameterized module for this purpose? What I mean is something like.

```
module module_generic(in, out)

parameter module_number;

case (module_number) 

   0 : out = logic_1; 

   1 : out = logic_2; 

   ...

   N : out = logic_N;

endcase

endmodule
```

By doing this, I can use generate statement to easily generate the code in the higher level module. Has anyone try this method before? Can it behave like the way I want? After synthesis, is it equivalent to the brute-force solution?

Comment: @toolic,  Thank you for your comment. However, I do not think it matters, it is just some random logic, such that out[wid - 1 : 0] = logic_n(in[wid - 1 ： 0]). It is because the logic itself is pretty random so that I use case statement. If it had some fixed pattern,  I could have used some other trick to take care of this matter.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? In is almost as though you are trying to create your own standard cells library.

Comment: @Greg, For example, I am trying to do some finite field multiplication with constant. I could have made the multiplier generic. This however would incur unnecessary overhead. So I want to build constant finite field multiplier for each element in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
module module_generic#(
    parameter module_number = 0
)(
  input logic in,
  output logic out);


generate
case (module_number) 

   0 : assign out = in; 

   //1 : assign out = logic_2; 

   //...

   //N : assign out = logic_N;

endcase
endgenerate

endmodule
```

This module can now be instantiated in your code with different inputs for parameter module_number. Unless a lot of the same code is used for each logic_X I don't really understand why you would want to do this. Nevertheless, as far as I could understand from your question, this should do it.

Edit in reply to comment:
Generate is used to *generate* repeated and conditional parts of the code based on some parameter (e.g. in a parameterized module). For example:

```
generate
if(INPUT_PARAMETER)
  assign out = in;
else //Tie low
  assign out = 0;
endgenerate
```

or

```
genvar N;
generate
  for(N = 0; N < INPUT_PARAMETER; N++) begin :la_someModule
    someModule(.out(out[N]), .in(in[N]));
  end
endgenerate
```

or both. (Take note of the label `la_someModule`. It is very smart to include this when using *generate for* , it simplifies debugging.)

Specifically answering the question you have asked here is hard. You have not provided enough information for me to understand what you need.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It looks just like the code in my question. The difference is you added generate. What is the purpose of using generate here? The idea is that for example, if I have N = 10000, I have to include 10000 lines for instantiate. But if I can make it generic, I can use a for loop to instantiate them.